# My Query work in mysql but not work with laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-4.2

Laravel Query:

```
$studentsFee = \FeeModal::query();
$studentsFee->groupBy('main_campus_id', 'session_id', 'class_info_id', 'section_id', 'stage_id')
                ->selectRaw('count(student_id) as student_strength,SUM(IF(paid_amount>0,1,0)) as submit_students,SUM(IF(paid_amount=0,1,0)) as not_submit_students, sum(paid_amount) as submit_amount')
                ->with('sessionMode', 'section',  'classInfo', 'stage')->get();

dd(count($studentsFee). ' Records' );
```

Result: 
 0 Records

Generated Query by `->toSql();`

```
string(281) "select count(student_id) as student_strength,SUM(IF(paid_amount>0,1,0)) as submit_students,SUM(IF(paid_amount=0,1,0)) as not_submit_students, sum(paid_amount) as submit_amount from `fee` group by `main_campus_id`, `session_id`, `class_info_id`, `section_id`, `stage_id`"
```

and when i execute this query in mysql it return 18 rows;

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to assign the result of the query to a variable:

```
$studentsQuery = \FeeModal::query();
$studentsFee = $studentsQuery->groupBy('main_campus_id', 'session_id', 'class_info_id', 'section_id', 'stage_id')
                ->selectRaw('count(student_id) as student_strength,SUM(IF(paid_amount>0,1,0)) as submit_students,SUM(IF(paid_amount=0,1,0)) as not_submit_students, sum(paid_amount) as submit_amount')
                ->with('sessionMode', 'section',  'classInfo', 'stage')->get();

dd(count($studentsFee). ' Records' );
```

Comment: Thanks alexw for your reply: but i don't get your point.. what you want to ask that.... where i forgot to assign the query result to a variable...

Comment: What I'm saying is that, unless this is some feature of Eloquent I'm unaware of, you need to assign the results of `get` to a variable (in my example, I'm calling the *result* `$studentsFee`.  In your example, `$studentsFee` is your *query*.  When you call `count` on a *query* object, it's not going to return the count of the *result* of the query - it's going to try and "count" the query itself.